# Haskell - finding bigrams from an input list of words

Tags: haskell, nlp, corpus

I'm following the NLPWP Computational Linguistics site and trying to create a Haskell procedure to find collocations (most common groupings of two words, like "United States" or "to find") in a list of words. I've got the following working code to find bigram frequency:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

-- | Function for creating a list of bigrams
-- | e.g. [("Colorless", "green"), ("green", "ideas")]
bigram :: [a] -> [[a]]
bigram []  = []
bigram [_] = []
bigram xs = take 2 xs : bigram (tail xs)

-- | Helper for freqList and freqBigram
countElem base alow = case (Map.lookup alow base) of
                       Just v -> Map.insert alow (v + 1) base
                       Nothing -> Map.insert alow 1 base

-- | Maps each word to its frequency.
freqList alow = foldl countElem Map.empty alow

-- | Maps each bigram to its frequency.
freqBigram alow = foldl countElem Map.empty (bigram alow)
```

I'm trying to write a function that outputs a Map from each bigram to [freq of bigram]/[(freq word 1)*(freq word 2)]. Could you possibly provide advice on how to approach it?

None of the following code is working, but it gives a vague outline for what I was trying to do.

```
collocations alow = 
  | let f key = (Map.lookup key freqBi) / ((Map.lookup (first alow) freqs)*(Map.lookup (last alow) freqs))
    in Map.mapWithKey f = freqBi
  where freqs = (freqList alow)
  where freqBi = (freqBigram alow)
```

I'm very new to Haskell, so let me know if you've got any idea how to fix the collocations procedure. Style tips are also welcome.

Comment: Style tip: It's a *function*, not a *procedure*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code looks sane, except for the final `colloctions` function.

I'm not sure why there's a stray pipe in there after the equals sign. You're not trying to write any kind of pattern guard, so I don't think that should be there.

`Map.lookup` returns a `Maybe` key, so trying to do division or multiplication isn't going to work. Maybe what you want is some kind of function that takes a key and a map, and returns the associated count *or zero* if the key doesn't exist?

Other than that, it looks like you're not too far off having this work.

Answer (score 0):

As I read it, your confusion stems from mistaking types, more or less. General advice: Use type signatures on all your top level functions and make sure they are sensible and what you expect of the function (I often do this even before implementing the function).

Let's take a look at your

```
-- | Function for creating a list of bigrams
-- | e.g. [("Colorless", "green"), ("green", "ideas")]
bigram :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

If you're giving in a list of Strings, you'll be getting a list of lists of Strings, so your bigram is a list.
You could decide to be more explicit (only allow Strings instead of sometype a - for the beginning at least). So, actually we get a list of Words an make a list of Bigrams from it:

```
type Word = String
type Bigram = (Word, Word)
bigram :: [Word] -> [Bigram]
```

For the implementation you can try to use readily available functions from Data.List, for example zipWith and tail.

Now your freqList and freqBigram look like

```
freqList :: [Word] -> Map Word Int
freqBigram :: [Word] -> Map Bigram Int
```

With this error messages of the compiler will be clearer to you. To point at it: Take care what you're doing in the lookups for the word frequencies. You're searching for the frequency of word1 and word2, and the bigram is (word1,word2).

Now you should be able to figure the solution out on your own, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I advise you to have a look at the function

```
insertWith :: Ord k => (a -> a -> a) -> k -> a -> Map k a -> Map k a
```

maybe you'll recognize the pattern if used

```
f freqs bg = insertWith (+) bg 1 freqs
```

Next as @MathematicalOrchid already pointed out your solution is not too far from being correct.

```
lookup :: Ord k => k -> Map k a -> Maybe a
```

You already took care of that in your `countElems` function.

what I'd like to note that there is this neat abstraction called `Applicative`, which works really well for problems like yours.

First of all you have to `import Control.Applicative` if you're using GHC prior to 7.10 for newer versions it is already at your fingertips.

So what does this abstraction provide, similar to `Functor` it gives you a way to handle "side effects" in your case the possibility of the failing lookup resulting in `Nothing`.

We have two operators provided by `Applicative`: `pure` and `<*>`, and in addition as every `Applicative` is required to be a `Functor` we also get `fmap` or `<$>` which are the latter is just an infix alias for convenience.

### So how does this apply to your situation?

```
<*> :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
<$> :: Functor f => a -> b -> f a -> f b
```

First of all you see that those two look darn similar but with `<*>` being slightly less familiar.

Now having a function

```
f :: Int -> Int
f x = x + 3
```

and 
    x1 :: Maybe Int
    x1 = Just 4
    x2 :: Maybe Int
    x2 = Nothing

one couldn't simply just `f y` because that wouldn't typecheck - but and that is the first idea to keep in mind. `Maybe` is a `Functor` (it is also an `Applicative` - it is even more an `M-thing`, but let's not go there).

```
f <$> x1 = Just 7
f <$> x2 = Nothing
```

so you can imagine the `f` looking up the value and performing the calculation inside the `Just` and if there is no value - a.k.a. we have the `Nothing` situation, we'll do what every lazy student does - be lazy and do nothing ;-).

Now we get to the next part `<*>`

```
g1 :: Maybe (Int -> Int)
g1 = Just (x + 3)
g2 :: Maybe (Int -> Int)
g2 = Nothing
```

Still `g1 x1` wouldn't work, but

```
g1 <*> x1 = Just 7
g1 <*> x2 = Nothing
g2 <*> x1 = Nothing -- remember g2 is Nothing
g2 <*> x2 = Nothing
```

### NEAT! - but still how does this solve your problem?

The 'magic' is using both operators ... for multi-argument functions

```
h :: Int -> Int -> Int
h x y = x + y + 2
```

and partial function application, which just means put in one value get back a function that waits for the next value.

```
GHCi> :type h 1
h 1 :: Int -> Int
```

Now the strange thing happens we can use  with a function like `h`.

```
GHCi> :type h1 <$> x1
h1 <$> x1 :: Maybe (Int -> Int)
```

well that's good because then we can use our `<*>` with it

```
y1 :: Maybe Int
y1 = Just 7
h1 <$> x1 <*> y1 = Just (4 + 7 + 2)
                 = Just 13
```

and this even works with an arbitrary number of arguments

```
k :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
k x y z w = ...
k <$> x1 <*> y1 <*> z1 <*> w1 = ...
```

So design a pure function that works with `Int`, `Float`, `Double` or whatever you like and then use the `Functor`/`Applicative` abstraction to make your `lookup` and frequency calculation work with each other.